# Problem: indexOf not taking effect when using script syntax in elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-painless

As shown in the figure, the indexOf of the longer id is valid but the indexOf of the shorter id is all -1.
[my search result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtU6h.png) I would like to know how to make the indexOf for these short ids also take effect!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `int array.indexOf(String)` maybe?